# Detour Pro not working on MSM setup

Tags: multi-site-manager, detour-pro

In preparation for taking a MSM site offline, I have added redirects from this site to the default site, however these do not seem to be working.

A couple of simple examples (the 'from' site is of the form https://www.ourdomain.com/de/)

```
/       https://www.ourdomain.com/en/       NULL    NULL    301 2
blog    https://www.ourdomain.com/en/blog   NULL    NULL    301 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved this by adding, either a wildcard character, or the site identifier to the beginning of the 'from' value:

```
de/blog    https://www.ourdomain.com/en/blog   NULL    NULL    301 2
```

Which I guess maybe due to the MSM path set up we have, ie as a postfix.